# Stack Overflow looks odd in Internet Explorer for Mac OS X

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface, browsers

Stack Overflow looks strange in Internet Explorer on Mac OS X. The top bar is displayed as a wide sidebar.

[image: top bar is displayed as wide sidebar]

Comment: Actually looks rather decent for a browser that wasn't even compatible with IE6...

Comment: I'll tell you what *is* odd... IE on OSX.

Comment: It's not officially a FAQ, but see [Which browsers are officially supported?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IE on Mac is way too old. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_for_Mac):

> On June 13, 2003, Microsoft announced that it was ceasing further development of Internet Explorer for Mac and the final update was released on July 11, 2003

IE was never known for compliance with standards (HTML, CSS, ...). You can't expect a web page to work with an eight year old broken browser.

Answer (score 8):

Considering that IE for MacOSX has been discontinued in favor of Safari when it was released, I highly doubt that this is truly a bug. There is most likely only about 1% of users world wide that still use it?

Comment: There should be alert for incompatible browser something like that.

Comment: @Manjot: The page looking all weird and broken is not an alert enough? I fail to believe that it's *only* SO (and no other site on the net) that looks broken in that browser.

Comment: @Piskvor'sSemifiniteMonkeys Other sites show incompatible error and guide user that Site supports Chrome,Firefox,Safari,IE etc.

Comment: @Manjot SO has an list of officially supported browsers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @gnat I am saying either show an alert or this link over there instead of showing incorrect thing.It doesn't look good.

Comment: @Manjot Why? This is the first time in the 3 years that the site exists that someone actually brought up IE for the Mac. Even Microsoft doesn't support it, nor do they show message when you visit their sites? Seriously? There is a list of supported browsers, if your using one that no one supports, then you have to accept things are not going to work, and use a browser that does.

Comment: Why doesn't StackOverflow tell me that it looks awful when I copy the source and view it in Notepad?  I mean, how lazy are you basterds?